# Possible for null character to get past regex?

Tags: java, regex

I use this regex in Java to allow only letters or numbers through as user input:

```
if (!string.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) {
}
```

A NULL character seems to have passed this. Is this possible? Or is this caused by something else?

Comment: I think "[a-zA-Z0-9]*" should be "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", the "*" quantifier allows between zero and infinte characters.

Comment: True ! @lbarros
Try `String string = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed. So an empty string can go through your regex.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/jZ2hI7/1 (note that it's giving 1 match with empty text)

Answer (score 0):

Change `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`
to     `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. 
Asterisk ("*") will allow zero characters.